# The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources. Magento 2.4.5-p1 on staging environment

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4.5p1

In the testing environment, it gives below errors,

```
    {
    "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Sales::actions_view"
    },
    "trace": "#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(68): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator->checkPermissions()\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator->validate()\n#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator\\Interceptor->___callParent('validate', Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Plugin/RestValidationPlugin.php(86): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): PayPal\\Braintree\\Plugin\\RestValidationPlugin->aroundValidate(Object(Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator\\Interceptor), Object(Closure))\n#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#6 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('validate', Array, NULL)\n#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(108): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator\\Interceptor->validate()\n#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->___callParent('resolve', Array)\n#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#11 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('resolve', Array, Array)\n#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(85): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->resolve()\n#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(195): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#17 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#20 /var/www/html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#21 {main}"
}
```

Its already Yes in: Allow OAuth Access Tokens.

I tried it in PHP script with Integration user as well as bearer token and not working in both scenario. The main thing is that live and local environment looks fine with same code file and DB setup.

**So my concern is that, Is any configuration on server can impact on this?**

PHP script:

```
    <?php  
 function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)  
 {  
      $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);  
      $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));  
      $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);  
      $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);  
      return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $secret, true));  
 }  
 function urlEncodeAsZend($value)  
 {  
      $encoded = rawurlencode($value);  
      $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);  
      return $encoded;  
 }  
// REPLACE WITH YOUR ACTUAL DATA OBTAINED WHILE CREATING NEW INTEGRATION

$consumerKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$consumerSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$accessToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$accessTokenSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
 $method = 'GET';  
 $url = 'http://xxxx.staging.com/rest/V1/orders/38024';  
   
 $data = [  
      'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,  
      'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),  
      'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA256',  
      'oauth_timestamp' => time(),  
      'oauth_token' => $accessToken,  
      'oauth_version' => '1.0',  
 ];  
 $data['oauth_signature'] = sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);  
 //print_r($data);
 $curl = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt_array($curl, [  
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,  
   CURLOPT_URL => $url,  
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [  
           'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')  
      ]  
 ]);  
 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 $orderData = json_decode($result,true);
 curl_close($curl);  
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($result);
 echo '</pre>';

?>
```

POSTMAN:
[image]

Comment: In the Authorization bearer token which token you passed? admin token or a customer token?

Comment: I tried accessToken from the integration user as well as the admin token. Both option is not working on my staging environment while it is working fine on live and locally.

Comment: Have you checked order id is proper or not?

Comment: Yes, order id i.e. entity_id is fine.

Comment: clean postman cookies and check again

Comment: checked but still same...

Comment: some one also got same issue on github forum https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/38426#issuecomment-1943451181

Answer (score 0):

For order detail rest API need to admin token to pass in the authorization bearer token

For Admin token please follow below steps,

- First of all, Set End Point of REST API :

  {{base_url}}/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token
- then set **Method** : **POST**
- **Headers**: **Content-Type: application/json**
- In the **request body**, include the following parameters:

  - username: your admin username
  - password: your admin password

  ```
  { 
    "username" : "admin login username",
    "password" : "admin login password"
  }
  ```

[image]